# How can I duplicate the split-view inside tabbed view seen in iTunes U 2.0 on iPad with Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: ipad, ios7, xamarin.ios

The new iTunes 2.0 app allows you to transition into  what appears to be a split-view inside a tabbed view on the iPad:

[image]

I would like to create something similar in my own app written using Xamarin.iOS. Basically I want to be able to first present a login screen (full screen), then after login push a tabbed interface on top. In these tabs, the user could enter for example search terms, and then I would like to present the result in the tab as a split-view (like in the iTunes app).

How can this be accomplished?

As far as I can see, the split-view is restricted to be used as a root view controller only, so there must be some trick to it?

Unless Apple is using a non-official API, or they have reimplemented the split-view or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to do and does not require any private APIs.

```
UISplitViewController split;
UIViewController master, detail, second;

master = new UIViewController();
detail = new UIViewController();
second = new UIViewController();

split = new UISplitViewController ();

split.ViewControllers = new UIViewController[] { master, detail };

split.Title = "Split";

tabs = new UITabBarController ();
tabs.ViewControllers = new UIViewController[] { split, second };

window.RootViewController = tabs;
```

Comment: In my app I have a login screen, which then transitions into a tabbed view that can contain other thing. Before when I have tried to push a UISplitViewController() I get a runtime exception that this is now allowed specifically for the split view controller. Has this been changed or how come it is so easy to do now, where it before wasn't allowed?

Comment: Pushing a SplitView onto the navigation stack is probably not allowed - and that is not what you asked in your question.  I would try making the Login controller my root controller, and then after login switch the root controller to be the tabcontroller containing the splitview.

Comment: Ah, but that's how it works in iTunes U - perhaps I didn't phrase the question correctly - I'll reword it. In my app you login and are then presented with a tabbed interface. In the tab interface, I would like the user to be able to enter search terms and then be presented with a splitview interface with the results of the search. But I can't present the splitview controller modally or non-modally it seems? - If it I have to switch the root controller, it seems quite brittle?

Comment: @jksoegaard I have been really struggling with this. Were you able to find out how to accomplish showing the splitView inside a tabbarcontroller with a single nav bar?

Comment: Sadly, no. If you do figure out a solution, I would love to hear about it! - In the end I solved by using a third party splitviewcontroller implementation.